# Python card game error

Tags: python, playing-cards

Well the script runs but I'm not getting any error's and it's not working right. More specificly, the program is supposed to deal out cards, then make a dictionary that gives each card a value depending on rank and suit. The cards are shuffled, dealt and then sorted. Who ever has the 3C starts first. How the computer is supossed to pick card is it goes through its list of cards and if It finds one that has a higher value then the previous card, it plays it. Well that works sometimes but If I play a card (usually T(10) or higher) it doesn't work, the computer plays a card that is worth less. Thanks for reading :D

```
import random

class player():
    def __init__(self, hand, name):
        self.hand = hand
        self.passed = False
        self.name = name

#computer ai for playing        
def complay(player):
    if '3C' in player.hand:
        playCard(player, '3C')
        return
    else:
        print previous[-1]
        for i in player.hand:
            if i > previous[-1]:
                playCard(player, i)
                return
            else:
                print 'Nothing higher', i, key[i]

#human options for playing a card
def humplay(player):
    if preplayer[-1] == 'player1':
        print 'hi'
        return
    else:
        done = False
        low = 0
        while done == False:
            print player.hand
            if low > 1:
                choose = raw_input('That card is to low, what card do you want to play?\n')
            else:
                choose = raw_input('What card do you want to play?\n')
                if choose not in player.hand:
                    print 'not in'
                    continue
                if key[choose] > key[previous[-1]]:
                    playCard(player, choose)
                    done = True
                else:
                    low == 1


#Function for playing a card
def playCard(player, card):
    place = player.hand.index(card)
    playcard = player.hand.pop(place)

    print player.name, 'has played the', playcard
    previous.append(playcard)
    preplayer.append(player.name)

#sorts the cards in hand        
def sort(player):
    for n in range(len(player.hand)):
        for i in player.hand:
            place = player.hand.index(i)
            try:
                if key[i] > key[player.hand[place + 1]]:
                    player.hand.insert(place + 1, player.hand.pop(place))
            except IndexError:
                pass

def main():
    global previous
    global preplayer
    global key
    suits = 'CSHD'
    mark = '3456789TJQKA2'
    deck = []
    players = []
    previous = ['3l']
    preplayer = []

    for card in mark:
        for suit in suits:
            deck.append(card+suit)

    key = {}
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        key[deck[i]] = i

    key['3l'] = -1

    for i in deck:
        print i, '\t\t', key[i]

    random.shuffle(deck)
    player1 = player(deck[0::2], 'player1')
    player2 = player(deck[1::2], 'player2')
    player3 = player(deck[2::4], 'player2')
    player4 = player(deck[3::4], 'player3')

    players = [player1, player2, player3, player4]

    sort(player1)
    sort(player2)
    sort(player3)
    sort(player4)

    if '3C' in player1.hand:
        preplayer.append(player2.name)
    if '3C' in player2.hand:
        preplayer.append(player1.name)

    while len((player1.hand or player2.hand or player3.hand or player4.hand)) != 0:
        if preplayer[-1] == 'player1':
            complay(player2)
        if preplayer[-1] == 'player2':
            humplay(player1)


main()
```

Comment: To indent code, you can select the region and hit the curly brace button "{}" (or type control-K.)

Comment: You can always enter your code in a text editor and tab everything over, giving it the right format.

Comment: It has to be a text editor that converts tabs to spaces though... such as emacs

Answer (score 2):

To determine whether the computer should play a card, you use

```
for i in player.hand:
    if i > previous[-1]:
        playCard(player, i)
        return
```

but your cards are simply strings like "3C" and "TD".  So when you use the ">" comparison, it compares them *as strings*.  But as a string 'TD' > 'QD', etc.  You should probably write a small function to determine the value of a card and use the results of that.

PS: Can you see other problems below?

```
player1 = player(deck[0::2], 'player1')
player2 = player(deck[1::2], 'player2')
player3 = player(deck[2::4], 'player2')
player4 = player(deck[3::4], 'player3')
```

Comment: >.< sorry what it was supposed to be was (can;t do code in comment) for i in player.hand: if key[i] > key[previous[-1]] >.< I'm so sorry to any who went through this. Thanks for the fast reply's though.